# Triggering builds of dependent projects in Travis CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

We have our single page javascript app in one repository and our backend server in another. Is there any way for a passing build on the backend server to trigger a build of the single page app?

We don't want to combine them into a single repository, but we do want to make sure that changes to one don't break the other.

Comment: Technically you could somehow push empty commit from withing server's travis.yml file to js app repo (or "empty" pull request). This would trigger it. Though you would have to work on having your credentials safe.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible to trigger another Travis job after a first one succeeds.  You can use the [`trigger-travis.sh`](https://github.com/plume-lib/trigger-travis/blob/master/trigger-travis.sh) script.

The script's [documentation](https://github.com/plume-lib/trigger-travis/) tells how to use it -- set an environment variable and add a few lines to your `.travis.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible yes and it's also possible to wait related build result.

I discover `trigger-travis.sh` from the previous answer but before that I was implementing my own solution (for full working source code: cf. pending pull request [PR196](https://github.com/geokrety/geokrety-website/pull/196/files) and [live result](https://travis-ci.org/geokrety/geokrety-website/jobs/444977991))

#### References

Based on travis API v3 documentation:

- trigger a build [triggering-builds](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/)
- get build information [resource/builds](https://developer.travis-ci.com/resource/builds#Builds)

You will need  a travis token, and setup this token as secreet environment variable on travis portal.

Following this doc, I were able to trigger a build, and wait for him.

### 1) make `.travis_hook_qa.sh`

(extract) - to trigger a new build :

```
REQUEST_RESULT=$(curl -s -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
   -H "Authorization: token ${QA_TOKEN}" \
   -d "$body" \
   https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/${QA_SLUG}/requests)
```

(it's `trigger-travis.sh` equivalent) You could make some customization on the build definition (with `$body`)

### 2) make `.travis_wait_build.sh`

(extract) - to wait a just created build, get build info :

```
    BUILD_INFO=$(curl -s -X GET \
       -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -H "Accept: application/json" \
       -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
       -H "Authorization: token ${QA_TOKEN}" \
       https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/${QA_SLUG}/builds?include=build.state\&include=build.id\&include=build.started_at\&branch.name=master\&sort_by=started_atdesc\&limit=1 )
    BUILD_STATE=$(echo "${BUILD_INFO}" | grep -Po '"state":.*?[^\\]",'|head -n1| awk -F "\"" '{print $4}')
    BUILD_ID=$(echo "${BUILD_INFO}" | grep '"id": '|head -n1| awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $8}')
```

You will have to wait until your timeout or expected final state..

Reminder: possible travis build states are `created`|`started` (and then) `passed`|`failed`