# Is it possible to have Travis-ci trigger another repository's build?

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, travis-ci, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I am trying to wrap my head around Travis-ci scripts but I am trying to figure out if what I want is even possible:

**Repo #1**:
 - my app to be built via travis-ci

**Repo #2**:
 - contains selenium/nightwatch tests that should run once **repo #1** is finished building

So this is the workflow I am aiming for:

- a PR in **Repo #1** gets merged
- Travis-ci builds **Repo #1** and completes successfully & deploys
- Travis-ci tells **Repo #2** to start building
- **Repo #2** installs the repo which triggers browserstack to begin running the selenium tests

Is this at all possible? I've been researching this for a few days and couldn't find a way to trigger a separate repo to build.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible Duplicate of: [Triggering builds of dependent projects in Travis CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118067/triggering-builds-of-dependent-projects-in-travis-ci)

Nevertheless, pasting the answer here: Yes, it is possible to trigger another Travis job after a first one succeeds. You can use the [trigger-travis.sh](https://github.com/mernst/plume-lib/blob/master/bin/trigger-travis.sh) script that is part of the [plume-lib](https://mernst.github.io/plume-lib/) library.

The script's documentation tells how to use it -- set an environment variable and add three lines to your .travis.yml file.

You can setup repo#1 and repo#2 using different jobs and use the above approach to trigger downstream job after successfully deployment has completed using job 1

Comment: I wasn't searching for the right terms but 'dependent builds' is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much BountyHunter!